# R: list containing lists

Tags: r

I would like to ask if anybody can find what is the mistake **in the 2nd construction** for not receiving the same list as in the 1st construction. Is there a way to refer to the **name** of an element of a list ? For example, somefunction(myList[[1]])==a1 ?

```
# construction #1
myList <- list(a1 = list(a2 = list("a21", "a22")), b1 = list("b1", "b2"))

# construction #2
myList                  <- list()
myList[[1]]             <- list(a1=list())
myList[[1]][[1]]        <- list(a2=list())
myList[[1]][[1]][[1]]   <- "a21"
myList[[1]][[1]][[2]]   <- "a22"
myList[[2]]             <- list(b1=list())
myList[[2]][[1]]        <- "b1"
myList[[2]][[2]]        <- "b2"
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make this simpler and look just at the first line:

```
myList <- list(a1 = "anything")
# vs
myList <- list()
myList[[1]] <- list(a1="anything")
```

In the first construction, slot 1 of the top list is named "a1" and contains "anything".  In the second construction, slot 1 of the top list is named nothing and contains a list whose first slot is named "a1" and contains "anything".

To make them similar, try:

```
myList <- list()
myList[["a1"]] <- "anything"
```

Comment: And is there a way to get the name "a1" instead of the content ?

Comment: To get the names, just use `names(myList)`.  For the names of a list contained within a list, just extract that list first (e.g. `names(myList[[1]])` ).

Comment: I was wondering how can I create a dictionary of list, and finally got it thanks to your answer, so thank you ;)